# Use HttpClientFactory in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which uses HttpClient to invoke a ASP.NET Web API REST service.

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task DumpWarehouseDataIntoFile(Warehouse myData, string path, string filename)
{ 
    try
    {
       //Hosted web API REST Service base url  
       string Baseurl = "http://XXX.XXX.XX.X:YYYY/";  

       //using (var client = new HttpClient())  --> I have declared client as an static variable
       //{  
        //Passing service base url  
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);  

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();  

        //Define request data format  
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));  
          
        // Serialize parameter to pass to the asp web api rest service
        string jsonParam = Newtonsoft.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData);

        //Sending request to find web api REST service resource  using HttpClient
        var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonParam, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsync("api/Warehouse/DumpIntoFile", httpContent);  

        //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
        if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)  
        {  
           // Some other sftuff here
        }
       //}
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          // Do some stuff here
     } // End Try

} // End DumpWarehouseDataIntoFile method
```

Now I am trying to install [HttpClientFactory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/5.0.0) nuget package in order to use HttpClientFactory instead of using HttpClient directly but I get an error when installing it. It seems it is not compatible. My ASP.NET MVC project targets to standard ASP.NET Framework 4.5 (Not Core).

Below the error when installing nuget package (sorry it is in Spanish). It says:

> Installing 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http 5.0.0'.
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http 5.0.0' was correctly installed. Adding
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http 5.0.0' to Application.InspeccionesModule...
> Installation error. Rolling back... Unable to install package
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http 5.0.0'. You are attempting to install this
> package in a project that has '.NETFramework, Version=v4.5' as
> destination, but the package does not contain assembly references or
> content files compatible with that framework.

[image]

How can I install HttpClientFactory package? And How can I configure base address url, request headers, etc. and then invoke PostAsync in HttpClientFactory in the same way as I do with classical HttpClient? Any snippet code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "but I get an error when installing it", well, we cannot see your screen, so please [edit] your question and paste the exact error message if you expect us to be able to help you.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have posted the error though this is in spanish.

Comment: Well, if you look at the Dependencies tab in the link you shared: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/5.0.0 - it says support is .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET Framework 4.6.1 - the error message complains you're targeting .NET Framework 4.5 (which is extremely old, and not supported). I'd *highly* recommend you to update to .NET Framework 4.8

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto ok so I can make the assumption that there is no possibility to use HttpClientFactory in NET 4.5

Comment: It's not an assumption, it's a defined constraint :)